# Upload part of the file to Google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to change a large file using google drive api, by uploading only changed part of the file, instead of entire file? I tried to find information about it in the API docs, but there's only support for continue uploading after connection reset. It seems to be an important feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. The Drive SDK treats files as atomic data blobs. It knows nothing about the format of content and hence what constitutes a change.